# Ajax refresher for XMLhttprequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want the XML doc to get read on a fixed interval, and avoid full page refresh everytime it looks for updates. The code below which is commented out works, but messes up the JQuery cycle. (which is based on http://buildinternet.com/project/totem/ )
Need some help with this.

```
//function refresh()
//    {

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "drift.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

//  }
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        var itemlength = item.length;
        var i;
        var html='';
        var today = new Date();

        var aktuella = [];
        $("#wrapper").append('<ul id=\'wrap\'></ul>');

        for (i = 0; i < itemlength; i++) {
        var postDate = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("expires")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var date = postDate.substring(8, 10);
        var month = postDate.substring(5, 7);
        var year = postDate.substring(0, 4);
        var expiredDate = new Date(year, month - 1, date);

        if (expiredDate > testDate) {
        aktuella.push(i);
        }
    };

    if (aktuella.length == 0 ) {
        var none = "<p>Info</p>";
        $('#wrapper').prepend(none);
    };

    if (aktuella.length == 1) {
        var expires = '<p>' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("expires")[0].parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent + '</p>';  
        $('#wrapper').prepend(expires);
    };

    if (aktuella.length > 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < aktuella.length; i++) {
        var expires = '<li id="' + i + '">' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("expires")[i].parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent + ' - Se Driftinfo</li>';  
        $('#wrap').prepend(expires);
        };
    };


    $(function(){
        $('#wrap').totemticker({
            row_height  :   '120px',
            next        :   '#ticker-next',
            previous    :   '#ticker-previous',
            stop        :   null,
            start       :   null,
            mousestop   :   true,
            });
        });
    }   

  //  refresh();
  //  setInterval("refresh()", 5000);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
Add this ti your script:

```
setInterval(function(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
}
};
}, milliseconds);
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. No xml gets loaded at all

Comment: did you replace milliseconds with what? 1000 for example? that is 1 second

Comment: Yes:
setInterval(function(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
  }
 };
}, 5000);

Comment: Should work. Try to put the setInterval after the funtion so. function myFunction(xml){} and setTinterval.

Comment: Does it show any error? I'm edit the script I write funtion instead function

Comment: parse.html:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: xhttp is not defined(anonymous function) @ parse.html:36

Comment: Write `var xhttp;` in global scope, then in the interval function use only `xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`.

Comment: Of course you also need to include `open` and `send` in the interval function.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Sure. xhttp must be global :(

Comment: of course (about adding them). Sorry again. Script edited with xhttp.open("GET", "drift.xml", true);
xhttp.send(); into the interval. So I understood well the question, and you, oceansmoving, can also read with a effort to read because the code is not tested. If you want, many people can make your full app. but not through here

Answer (score 0):

try now with this. There where a mistake. funtion instead function and the interval after the function to call

```
function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    var itemlength = item.length;
    var i;
    var html='';
    var today = new Date();

    var aktuella = [];
    $("#wrapper").append('<ul id=\'wrap\'></ul>');

    for (i = 0; i < itemlength; i++) {
    var postDate = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("expires")   [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var date = postDate.substring(8, 10);
    var month = postDate.substring(5, 7);
    var year = postDate.substring(0, 4);
    var expiredDate = new Date(year, month - 1, date);

    if (expiredDate > testDate) {
    aktuella.push(i);
    }
 };

setInterval(function(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "drift.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}, milliseconds);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If 
xhttp.open("GET", "drift.xml", true);
xhttp.send(); 
isn't part of the function nothing happens.

Check my original post, that describes what happens if you do add it to the refresh function. It works but the totempicker cycle gets messed up

Comment: It seems the code is working well. Only wait first five seconds. You can call the function on load and later after 5 seconds the scroll runs up

Comment: Look at my post below

Comment: The post whit url examples? It seems to work. What's the problem now? If you don't want to wait the 5 seconds simple call to the function onload. Add this:  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "drift.xml", true);
xhttp.send();  to your script and the xml data will be loaded on load the page

Comment: Compare 1 and 2, sure it's moving but way to fast and in the wrong order etc.

Comment: That's another question

Comment: No it's really not. From my original post: "The code below which is commented out works, but messes up the JQuery cycle. (which is based on http://buildinternet.com/project/totem/ ) Need some help with this."

Answer (score 0):

Here is the site without any attempt to refresh the ajax:

http://socialsiberia.com/dash/test1.html

And here is the weird behaviour that occurs when I add the code below:

http://socialsiberia.com/dash/test2.html

```
setInterval(function(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
        }
    };

xhttp.open("GET", "test.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    
function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    var itemlength = item.length;
    var i;
    var html='';
    var today = new Date();

    var aktuella = [];
    $("#wrapper").append('<ul id=\'wrap\'></ul>');

    for (i = 0; i < itemlength; i++) {
    var postDate = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("expires")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var date = postDate.substring(8, 10);
    var month = postDate.substring(5, 7);
    var year = postDate.substring(0, 4);
    var expiredDate = new Date(year, month - 1, date);

    if (expiredDate > testDate) {
    aktuella.push(i);
    }
};

if (aktuella.length == 0 ) {
    var none = "<p>Info</p>";
    $('#wrapper').prepend(none);
};

if (aktuella.length == 1) {
    var expires = '<p>' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("expires")[0].parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent + '</p>';  
    $('#wrapper').prepend(expires);
};

if (aktuella.length > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < aktuella.length; i++) {
    var expires = '<li id="' + i + '">' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("expires")[i].parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent + ' - Se Driftinfo</li>';  
    $('#wrap').prepend(expires);
    };
};


$(function(){
    $('#wrap').totemticker({
        row_height  :   '120px',
        next        :   '#ticker-next',
        previous    :   '#ticker-previous',
        stop        :   null,
        start       :   null,
        mousestop   :   true,
        });
    });
}

funtion makeinterval(){

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
 }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "drift.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}

setInterval(function(){
 makeInterval();
}, 5000);
makeinterval()
```

Comment: This is the result of the above:
http://socialsiberia.com/dash/test2.html